# can typescript infer the string literal type without `as const`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In order for js to use the api well, how to make the compiler infer `"bar"` type instead of `string` without using `as const`.

```js
declare function define<T>(
  options: {
    foo: string;
    bar: T;
  }
): void;

declare function create<T>( cmd: T ): T;

define( {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: create( "bar" ) // It still string, instead of "bar"
} );
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX1ES1RAB4AVAPgAoAoeeHAB2zwGcAueAb3oaRw4ubDDGIBzANx8GAI1hdy0hgF9aASi4A3HFmDTaoSLAQp0rfGDhQMZKtXhgAtsEXxN8JbUMgiJB7wMiIJcAETBOKEANHzyMFxWIDYgDqFxoe60Ku6SQA)

Comment: Is `T` always going to be a subtype of `string`?  If so you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoDl8w).  If not then what possible types will it be?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373756/typescript-constrain-generic-to-string-literal-type-for-use-in-computed-object-p#answer-66011942), a util type can help:

```js
type StringLiteral<T> = T extends string ? string extends T ? never : T : never;

declare function define<T>(
  options: {
    foo: string;
    bar: StringLiteral<T>;
  }
): void;
```